# How to set the css properties with its own data-attributes?

Tags: jquery, css, custom-data-attribute

Say I have this little snippet:

```
<p data-color="red">Hello world</p>
```

An I want to set its color to its own data-attribute, like this:

```
$('p').css({

    color: $(this).data('color')
});
```

**For some reason, that doesn't work.** Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$(this)` is not the `p->this` and so will not work inside the arg.

Comment: @Vega - Is there a way to get to the `$("p")` ?

Comment: See Daniel's answer and that seems to be the only way. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10589446/297641

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` refers to something else, not to the `p`. Try putting it in a function.

```
$('p').css('color', function() { return $(this).data('color'); });
```

Comment: What if I want to use an object literal to set a whole bunch of css properties?

Comment: Wrapping it with an each would do the trick I guess. Shame though I can't get to the data-attributes directly then.

Comment: you could always write a pluggin.

Comment: True. :) Things like these are a nice excuse to create plugins.

Answer (score 3):

```
​$('p').css('color', function() {
    return $(this).data('color');
});​​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thesystemrestart/BmGnu/)**

Answer (score 2):

You could store the whole data in an object before setting the css properties to avoid a loop. Something like :

```
var $p = $('p'),
    data = $p.data();

$p.css({
    color: data.color,
    fontSize: data.fontSize
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aYpXZ/

Comment: Cute. I like the neatness of it. This can be useful for creating a plugin that would make it possible to use the data-attributes the way I want it.